# What are the available approaches to calculate expressions using .Net library for a bulk data in Oracle?

Tags: .net, oracle

In an Oracle database, I have a bulk of expressions that should be calculated using a .Net library. What I've done so far is creating a windows service that fetches the expressions from a queue, processes them and the write the result.

I wonder if I could find a more efficient way, since many records could be inserted every second, so I'm afraid of a performance issues later.

I though about moving this processing to an Oracle Job, but calculating the expression should be made in a .Net library; and I have no clue whether it's possible to use a .Net library in an Oracle procedure.

Is the .Net service with the queue the best option, or is there any other options?

Comment: Is oracle hosted on windows?  If so you may use http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28376/intro.htm

Comment: I'm not sure how well they perform, but this also sets them out nicely. http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/storedfunc/vs2_otn.htm I've not used them but have use the MSSQL equivalent and it is OK.

Comment: seems to be good.. I'm reading about it

Comment: have you considered converting these functions to pl/sql?

Comment: @tbone: I said that I had a problem with dealing with the .Net library. Now, I'm considering Mike's solution.

Comment: @Homam you say "I have a bulk of expressions that should be calculated using a .Net library"... my point is why MUST they be in .NET?  Why not take advantage of pl/sql since you're doing these operations in Oracle?

Comment: @tbone: well, actually I already work with expression parser from a third party company and I cannot replace it.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments I think you will be able to use Oracle Database Extensions for .NET ( [docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28376/intro.htm](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28376/intro.htm)).  This allows you to use .NET in a similar way to UDF's and should accomplish what you need.  Evaluate the performance carefully and be sure that the .NET code is robust enough to not cause problems to the Oracle server itself.  I have seen a similar approach used with MSSQL using some unmanaged objects and it caused issues.